# What is wrong with this code that tries to print a decrementing sequence of numbers?

Tags: python-3.x

I am very new to python and want to write a program that counts down. It has to start at 100 and ends at 1 or 0. How do i have to do that?
This is what i've got now:

```
def countdown(n):
while n > 0:
    print (n)
    n = n =2**123
print('Blastoff')

countdown(200)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n = n =2**123
```

??? What is this supposed to do? What are you trying to accomplish by setting `n` to 2 to the 123th power? I think

```
n = n - 1
```

or

```
n -= 1
```

would be more appropriate.

Comment: Agreed, just change that one line and you're there, add a delay for a more...realistic countdown, as is it will probably finish in less than a second.

Comment: ya that was a suggestion more for the OP not you.

Comment: @JakeSellers Yup, got it, that's just to let you know my opinion :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def countdown(count):
    while (count >= 0):
        print ('The count is: ', count)
        count -= 1

countdown(10)
print ("Good bye!")
```

If you want to it count down in the terms of actual seconds, which I'm going to guess is what you are going for it would be done by causing the countdown to sleep for 1 second at each iteration:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time

def countdown(count):
    while (count >= 0):
        print ('The count is: ', count)
        count -= 1
        time.sleep(1)

countdown(10)
print ("Good bye!")
```

The output is:

```
The count is:  10
The count is:  9
The count is:  8
The count is:  7
The count is:  6
The count is:  5
The count is:  4
The count is:  3
The count is:  2
The count is:  1
The count is:  0
Good bye!
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

In python, the indentation matters. All of the lines inside the function have to be indented.

Your method should have been:

```
def countdown(n):
     while n > 0:
         print (n)
         n = n-1
     print("Blastoff")
```

or a more pythonic way could be:

```
def countdown(n):
    for i in reversed( range(n) ):
        print i
    print "Blastoff"
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy way is using range with negative increment parameter. 
For example:

```
for n in range(10,0,-1):
    print(n)
```

Another way: you can use yield command. It's using for making a generator. It's like to return command. 
For example:

```
#this is generator function
def countdown(start,last):
    n=start
    while(n>last):
        yield n
        n-=1

for n in countdown(10,0):
    print(n)
```

Answer (score -1):

i would simply wright something like:

```
import time
num1 = 100
num2 = 0
while (num1 > num2):
    print num1
    num1 = num1 - 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Hay Try This You Can Input The Number You Need To Count Down From:

```
import time

numTimes = int(input("How Many Seconds Do You Wish To Have Untill LiftOff: "))
def countdown(count):
    while (count >= 0):
        print ("LiftOff In: ", count)
        count -= 1
        time.sleep(1)

countdown(numTimes)
print ("!WE HAVE LIFT OFF!")
```

Comment: please don't capitalize words like that, it's annoying.

Answer (score -1):

The following code should work:

```
import time
start = int(input("How many seconds do you want?\nSeconds: "))
for i in range(start,-1,-1):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(i)
print "Countdown finish!"
```

Comment: This answer has appeared in low quality posts. To prevent it from happening always add some explanation of the code.